# Современная веб-разработка

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

В последнее время в веб-разработку пришли всяческие новомодные технологии, типа Node.js, Angular, Grunt, Gulp, Sass, Less и тому подобное. Лично я сторонник традиционной разработки в рамках набора HTML, JS, CSS, PHP, который удовлетворяет практически все необходимые заказчику хотелки, но меня до сих пор мучает мысль, что я что-то упускаю, и через какое-то время моя кандидатура на рынке труда потеряет ценность. Необходимо ли в настоящее время владеть новыми технологиями разработки, и достаточно ли высок КПД, который будет получен от их изучения?

Comment: Если с перечисленными познаниями еще хватает на 1 пачку доширака в день - это уже огромный успех

Comment: @РашенБеар, вы, видимо, слабо знакомы со статистикой по востребованности специалистов и уровню их зарплат.

Comment: @Pyramidhead специалистов по чему? Базовые знания PHP и возможность сделать на нем WP - шаблон не делают человека специалистом по PHP. Если для "JS-программиста" Node.js - это такая лишняя новомодная технология то JS-программист из него такой же как и PHP. С базовыми знаниями PHP и JS остается быть фронтенд специалистом. Только вот фронтенд для которого "Angular, Grunt, Gulp, Sass, Less и тому подобное" - это новомодные технологии никому уже не нужен

Comment: @РашенБеар, а где вы увидели, что речь о базовых знаниях PHP и JS? Быть может, вы не знаете, но существуют Yii, Zend, Symphony, Laravel etc. Node - не панацея и для многих задач его использовать бессмысленно. Однако сейчас очень часто фронтенд специалисты даже не знают чистый js и везде пытаются задействовать Node, Angular, React и т.д.

Comment: @Pyramidhead `а где вы увидели` в контексте. `Yii, Zend, Symphony, Laravel ` и другие новомодные технологии, да

Comment: @РашенБеар, замечу, что их нет в списке `новомодных технологий` и они вполне `в рамках набора HTML, JS, CSS, PHP`.

Comment: @Pyramidhead в рамках набора фреймворков нет

Comment: @РашенБеар, php-фреймворки не в рамках php? Железная логика. Впрочем, не вижу смысла продолжать эту бессмысленную дискуссию.

Comment: @Pyramidhead они так же в рамках PHP как и `Angular` в рамках JS

Answer (score 3):

Откровенно говоря, это немножко оффтопик, но всё же постараюсь дать ответ. Думаю, темы здесь стоит разделить (как обычно в веб-разработке) на бэкэнд и фронтэнд.

#### Back end: PHP vs X

ПХП часто противопоставляется другим, более молодым северным технологиям (Node.js, Python, Go, и т.д). Аргументы при этом применяются очень схожие: *X* – более приятный и мощный язык, у него бóльшая производительность, легко настраивается, а многие популярные современные технологии поддерживаются прямо из коробки (ВебСокеты, параллелизм, и т.д). И популярность этих технологий всё растёт.

В то же время, на PHP уже написано огромное множество сайтов, модулей, для него издавна существует куча уроков, и им уже владеет множество разработчиков, что делает разработку и поддержку сайтов на нём относительно недорогой.

В целом, любой сайт можно разработать на любых технологиях. Но где-то это будет проще и эффективнее, а где-то нет. На мой взгляд, для серверов со сложными внутренними алгоритмами, обработкой больших данных, параллелизмом обязательно нужно использовать одну из технологий *X*, созданных как раз для этого. PHP же в этих целях редко применяют, зато почти постоянно для популярных бизнес-решений и создания сайтов не ИТ компаний (всякие сайты-визитки и подобное).

Предлагаю дополнительные материалы по этой теме: [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273259/) и [два](https://www.netguru.co/blog/nodejs-vs-php).

#### Front end: фреймворки vs только свои HTML,CSS,JS

Данный вопрос тоже обобщу до использования фреймворков в целом (Anngular, React, [Vue](https://medium.com/unicorn-supplies/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-a-2017-comparison-c5c52d620176)). Все они созданы с целью упростить жизнь фронтэнд разработчикам, дать возможность легко прикручивать интересные, полезные и красивые фичи: шаблоны страниц, автоматический биндинг данных, работа с сайтом на одной HTML странице, и т.д. Это классные вещи, не стоит их недооценивать.

Опять же, можно обойтись и без них, реализовать всё своим JS кодом или искать готовые библиотеки для отдельных фич... А где-то это всё попросту не нужно.

[Статья о поводах для использования AngularJS](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/react-vs-angularjs-how-the-two-compare-8t6f1ioan). Также, в сравнении этих технологий друг с другом можно увидеть их достоинства не только друг перед другом, но и перед их отсутствием: [Angular vs React](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/react-vs-angularjs-how-the-two-compare-8t6f1ioan) и [Angular vs. React vs. Vue](https://medium.com/unicorn-supplies/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-a-2017-comparison-c5c52d620176).

#### Статистика

Да, в наше время всё ещё полно рабочих мест по специальности ПХП-программиста, но беглый поиск по StackOverflow Jobs говорит, что крупные ИТ компании почти всегда используют большой стек современных технологий, и вероятно, что в будущем эта тенденция будет только увеличиваться, становиться повсеместной: [***SO Jobs:*** back end](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=back+end) и [***SO Jobs:*** front end](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=front+end).

---

### Заключение

Соответственно, если Вы хотите сильно расширить свой кругозор и получить возможность заняться проектами в новых тематиках и новых масштабах, то стоит учить новое.